# borderColor in baposter

Tags: baposter

I'm not able to unify colours of box header and box border. The colours are very similar but never the same. I tried it to set them globally as well as localy but without any success.

```
\documentclass[a0paper, portrait, margin = 2.2em]{baposter}

\usepackage{url}            % For \url
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\graphicspath{{pix/}}   % Root directory of the pictures 

\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{230, 184, 0}
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{230, 184, 0}
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{255, 255, 250}
\definecolor{backgroundcol}{RGB}{255, 255, 250}
\definecolor{higlightcol}{RGB}{255, 110, 0}

\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{1.5em}#1}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
%\patchcmd{<command>}{<code to replace>}{<code>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}{0em}{0.5\boxwidth}{}{}
\patchcmd{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}{west}{center}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{poster}{
    borderColor=bordercol,
    headerColorOne=headercol1,
    headerColorTwo=headercol1,
    headerFontColor=headerfontcol,
    boxColorOne=boxcolor,
    boxColorTwo=boxcolor,
    headershape=rectangle,
    headerborder=closed,
    headerfont=\Large\scshape,
    textborder=rectangle,
    headerheight=0.09\textheight,
    colspacing=0.35em, % Column spacing
    bgColorOne=backgroundcol,
    bgColorTwo=backgroundcol
}
%%% Eye Cacther %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{
    Eye Catcher, empty if option eyecatcher=false - unused
}
%%% Title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\sf\scshape
    Unifying colours of box header and border in baposter
}
%%% Authors %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{
    Box Expert
}


\headerbox{Standard box}{name = box1, column = 0, row = 0}{
This is standard box.
}

\headerbox{Highlighted box}{name = box2, column = 0, below = box1,
boxColorOne = purple!40, headerColorOne = purple, headerColorTwo = purple, borderColor = purple}{
This should be highlighted box.
}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Difference is still apparent:
[image]

Any suggestions how to make the colours to be the same are welcomed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that per default the background of the title is colour shade, even if you specify both colours of the shading to be the same, there is still a colour shading between the two colours.

The colour shading is done via some `pgf` magic which uses another colour model than the lines around your box which causes the colours to look slightly different -- or something like that, I did not really investigate this problem.

Luckily one can simply switch of the colour shading using `headershade=plain`.

```
\documentclass[a0paper, portrait, margin = 2.2em]{baposter}


\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
    headershape=rectangle,
    headerborder=closed,
    textborder=rectangle
}{}{}{}


\headerbox{Highlighted box}{%
    headerColorOne = purple, 
    headershade=plain,
    borderColor = purple
}{
This should be highlighted box.
}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this works! Thank you. Interesingly, color now responds to border not to header but at least is unified!

Answer (score 3):

## Update

`tikz` now supports CMYK shadings since version 3.1.3. So the original example will work without any changes.

---

Another solution to this problem is now available using a new package `pgf-cmykshadings` which provides support for CMYK shadings for `pgf`.

The fundamental problem is this: `baposter` loads the `xcolor` package with the `cmyk` option. This means that all the colours in the document will be output in CMYK. This is true even of the colours defined in the MWE using the RGB model.

But `pgf` is *not* able to output shadings in CMYK, only RGB. So the headerCol, which is a shading will be output in RGB. But the border will be output in CMYK. The result is a colour mismatch.

In order to get consistent colours there are two other options apart from that listed in the other answer:

1. Select the `rgb` colour model in the `xcolor` package which will force all colours to be RGB and therefore match the shadings. Change the start of the document document to:

   ```
   \documentclass[a0paper, portrait, margin = 2.2em]{baposter}
   \selectcolormodel{rgb}
   ```

[image]

2. Load the new package `pgf-cmykshadings` which provides support for CMYK shadings. It's also necessary to load `xcolor` with the `cmyk` option to avoid an option clash. All colours including the shadings will now be in CMYK. Change the start of your file to:

   ```
   \RequirePackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
   \RequirePackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
   \documentclass[a0paper, portrait, margin = 2.2em]{baposter}
   ```

[image]

Comment: +1 Great answer!