# Gradient color in Xebaposter header

Tags: color, baposter

I can not get the gradient color for header color using `Xbaposter`, when i compile with Xelatex, gives only simple color,  the problem  in two lines `headerColorOne=black,`and `headerColorTwo=lightblue,` with the definition of the color `\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}`. the .cls file can be downloaded from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/xebaposter?lang=en).
The 3 lines are marked with problen in the MWE:

```
\documentclass[debug,a0paper,portrait,persian]{xebaposter}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize} % for \smaller
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xecolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}% for making inline list.
\setlist{noitemsep}% Save space in lists.


\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{papersize={90cm,170cm},verbose=ture,reset}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 %%%% Some math symbols used in the text
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % Format 
% \newcommand{\RotUP}[1]{\begin{sideways}#1\end{sideways}}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % Multicol Settings
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \setlength{\columnsep}{0.7em}
% \setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

%% Begin of Document
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%% Setting User Defined Background %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%if you want to use your preferred background, you should set background=user in poster settings.
\background{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \fill [yellow!20] {(current page.south east) rectangle (current page.north west)};%
    \draw (current page.center)+(0pt,0pt) node[anchor=center,opacity=.1]
    {\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{shariflogo}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Here starts the poster
%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Format it to your taste with the options
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \definecolor{silver}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.3}
      \definecolor{yellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.9,0.0}
      \definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
      \definecolor{black}{cmyk}{0,0,0.0,1.0}
      \definecolor{darkYellow}{cmyk}{0,0,1.0,0.5}
      \definecolor{darkSilver}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.1}

      \definecolor{lightyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.3,0.0}
      \definecolor{lighteryellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0.0}
      \definecolor{lighteryellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0.0}
      \definecolor{lightestyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.05,0.0}



%\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Problem
      \begin{poster}%
      % Poster Options
      {
      eyecatcher=true,
      % Color style
      bgColorOne=lightyellow,
      bgColorTwo=yellow,
      borderColor=reddishyellow,
      headerColorOne=yellow,%headerColorOne=black, %  Problem
      headerColorTwo=reddishyellow,%headerColorTwo=lightblue, %  Problem
%      headerFontColor=silver,
      boxColorOne=red,
      boxColorTwo=lighteryellow,
      % Format of textbox
      textborder=faded,
      % Format of text header
      headerborder=closed,
      headerheight=0.1\textheight,
      headershape=roundedleft,
      headershade=plain,
%      headerfont=\Large, %Sans Serif
      boxshade=shadetb,%plain,
      background=user,%plain,
      linewidth=2pt,
      grid=false,
      }
 % Eye Catcher
 {
      \includegraphics[height=0.07\textheight]{logo}
 }
 % Title
 {عنوان پوستر عنوان پوستر عنوان پوستر عنوان پوستر عنوان پوستر عنوان پوستر عنوان پوستر 
}
 % Authors
 {\large نام۱ نام خانوادگی۱, نام۳ نام خانوادگی۲, نام۳ نام خانوادگی۳ 
 \\%[1em]
 {\normalsize\texttt{\lr{name1@mail.org, name2@mail.edu, name3@mail.com}}}}
 % University logo
 {
\begin{tabular}{r}
    \includegraphics[height=0.07 \textheight]{shariflogo}\\
\end{tabular}
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Now define the boxes that make up the poster
%%%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%% Each box has a name and can be placed absolutely or relatively.
%%% The only inconvenience is that you can only specify a relative position 
%%% towards an already declared box. So if you have a box attached to the 
%%% bottom, one to the top and a third one which should be inbetween, you 
%%% have to specify the top and bottom boxes before you specify the middle 
%%% box.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=introduction,column=0,row=0]{\textxecolor{red}{مقدمه}}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
برای تست بسته سعی می‌کنم که یک خط فارسی بنگارم\LTRfootnote{test} تا نتیجه آن را در این پوستر مشاهد کنم\footnote{تست پانویسی}.
\end{posterbox}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=phase2,column=1,span=1]{فاز دو: پردازش}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.6\textwidth}
%\centering
%  \vspace{-10pt}
%{
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{fig3}
%}
%  \vspace{-20pt}
\end{wrapfigure}

\ptext[2]

محاسبات لازم:
\begin{align*}
f_1 &= \frac{HXY-HXY1}{max\{HX,HY\}}\\
f_2 &= \sqrt{1-\exp\{-2(HXY2-HXY)\}} 
\end{align*}

{\scriptsize 
\centerline{\begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
C(i, j) is an element of GLC matrix and N is number of gray-levels.
\end{minipage}}
\vspace{-.5mm}
$$\begin{array}{l}

\displaystyle C_x(i) =\sum_{j=1}^N C(i,j), \quad C_y(i)=\sum_{i=1}^N C(i,j)\\
\displaystyle  HXY = -\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N C(i,j) \log\{C(i,j)\}\\
\displaystyle  HXY1 = -\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N C(i,j) \log\{C_x(i)\times C_y(j)\}\\
\displaystyle  HXY2 = -\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N C_x(i)\times C_y(j) \log\{C_x(i)\times C_y(j)\}\\
\end{array}$$
}
\end{posterbox}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=phase3,column=2,span=1,row=0]{استخراج ویژگی‌های: دوتایی}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ptext[7]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=1.1,height=7cm]{fig4}}
\end{posterbox}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=phase4,column=2,span=1,below=phase3]{جداسازی}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ptext[6]
\end{posterbox}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=results,column=1,span=2,below=phase2]{نتایج}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{fig6}}
    \ptext[2-3]

    \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=.7]{fig5}}
\end{multicols}
\end{posterbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=imagedataset,column=0,span=1,below=introduction]{پایگاه داده تصاویر}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
    \item ۱۱۰ تصویر سالم
    \item ۶۶ تصویر ناسالم
    \item ۶۰ درصد تصاویر برای آموزش به کار برده شده‌اند و مابقی برای تست درستی الگوریتم.
    \item وبسایت \url{http://www.med.harvard.edu/AANLIB/home.html}
\end{itemize}
\end{posterbox}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=phase1,column=0,span=1,below=imagedataset]{فاز یک{:} پیش‌پردازش}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ptext[12]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item پشت زمینه
    \item زنگ روشن
    \item بخش‌های نامرتبط
\end{enumerate}
\ptext[14]

برای هر $\lambda \geq 0$ ورودی نیمه‌مثبت $x\in R^m$ صحیح به‌دست می‌آید البته اگر برای $\lambda X$، $\lambda Y$ ($\lambda >0$) آنگاه ($\lambda y$ و $\lambda x$)

\ptext[16-17]
\end{posterbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=adhoc,column=0,span=1,below=phase1]{همینطوری}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\textxecolor{red}
{برای پر کردن فضا استفاده شده است. برای پر کردن فضا استفاده شده است. برای پر کردن فضا استفاده شده است. 
برای پر کردن فضا استفاده شده است. برای پر کردن فضا استفاده شده است. برای پر کردن فضا استفاده شده است. 
سلام}
\end{posterbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=references,column=1,span=2,below=results]{منابع}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \smaller
%     \bibliographystyle{ieee}
     \renewcommand{\section}[2]{\vskip 0.05em}
       \begin{thebibliography}{1}\itemsep=-0.01em
       \setlength{\baselineskip}{0.4em}
       \bibitem{}
       محمود سیستانی, سیدجواد علوی, رضا حسینی
    , ''بررسی پوستر در فضای فارسی``
    , کنفرانس سالانه کامپیوتر, صفحات 868--871, بهار ۱۳۹۲.
       \end{thebibliography}
\end{posterbox}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=ack,column=0,span=2,below=references]{قدردانی}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
با تشکر از دکتر \lr{Brian Amberg}؛ این کار فارسی‌سازی پوستری است که توسط ایشان طراحی شده است\footnote{\url{http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/}}.
\end{posterbox}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{posterbox}[name=ack,column=2,span=1,below=references]{خالی}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی 
فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی فضای خالی 
\end{posterbox}%%
\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/456718. Try adding \RequirePackage{pgf-cmykshadings} before \documentclass. It probably needs to go before \documentclass to avoid option clashes when baposter loads xcolor.

Comment: It works fine, thank you @Ross

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

Since version 3.1.3, `tikz` now supports CMYK shadings, so it is no longer necessary to load `pgf-cmykshadings`. (The bug is not fixed yet though.)

---

There is a clash between the `pgfpages` package (loaded by `[xe]baposter`), the `pgfsys-dvipdfmx` driver (used by `xelatex`) and shadings. I don't know exactly what is going on, but the net result is that shadings don't work with `xelatex`. I have submitted a bug report at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/520.

Anyway, it does work if we specify that we want the `pgfsys-dvipdfm` driver, though this may have other side effects.

Also in your poster setup you have `headershade=plain` which disables the shading in the header altogether. So you want to remove this option.

And as mentioned in the comments if you are going to use shadings in `(xe)baposter` it is recommended to use the `pgf-cmykshadings` package so you don't get unexpected colour mismatches. In your particular example this won't happen, but there is always potential. This is because all solid colours will be output in CMYK, but all gradients will be output in RGB. This happens regardless of how you define colours in your document. If you use a colour in your gradient that you also use elsewhere as a solid colour they will look different. In light of this I redefined your `lightblue` colour in CMYK so it will look approximately the same on screen as your RGB definition.

All these things can be done by putting this before your `\documentclass`:

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\RequirePackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
```

By the way in future it would make it easier if you can make your example more minimal. It helps us narrow down the problems faster.

## MWE

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\RequirePackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait,persian]{xebaposter}

\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.68,0.25,0.0,0.0}
%\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
    borderColor=reddishyellow,
    headerColorOne=black,
    headerColorTwo=lightblue,
    headerborder=closed,
    headershape=roundedleft,
    headerfont=\Large,
    background=none
  }{}{}{}

  \begin{posterbox}{جداسازی}
    \ptext[6]
  \end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]