# How to remove the empty white space in Background for Xebaposter

Tags: backgrounds, xepersian, baposter

Using background for a poster using Xebaposter shows an empty space on the left margin as shown in figure1, this quetion is based on [this anwer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478111/gradient-color-in-xebaposter-header/478134#478134).

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\RequirePackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
\documentclass[a0paper,landscape,persian]{xebaposter}

\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.68,0.25,0.0,0.0}
%\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
    borderColor=reddishyellow,
    headerColorOne=black,
    headerColorTwo=lightblue,
    headerborder=closed,
    headershape=roundedleft,
    headerfont=\Large,
    background=shadetb,%user,%plain,none ,shadetb,
    %background=none
  }{}{}{}

  \begin{posterbox}{جداسازی}
    \ptext[6]
  \end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The answer to this issue lead to another issue witch is the text exceeds the left margins if i add the options [column=0,span=4,row=0]:

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\RequirePackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
\documentclass[margin=0cm,a0paper,landscape,persian]{xebaposter} % <- added margin

\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Yas}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % <- added 0pt \parindent

\definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.68,0.25,0.0,0.0}
%\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{-1\baselineskip} % <- added negative baselineskip
\begin{poster}{
    borderColor=reddishyellow,
    headerColorOne=black,
    headerColorTwo=lightblue,
    headerborder=closed,
    headershape=roundedleft,
    headerfont=\Large,
    background=shadetb,%user,%plain,none ,shadetb,
    %background=none
  }{}{}{}

  \begin{posterbox}[column=0,span=4,row=0]{جداسازی}
    \ptext[6]
  \end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The question, I guess, is: how to remove that white margin?

Comment: It is done, thank you

Comment: @AbdelhakElfengour If you have solved the issue yourself, you should add a self-answer. Good self-answers are always appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the right to left design, there is something wrong setting the margins and posterbox layout. Rather than solve that, here is a pragmatic solution.

The class provides a key for the user to manually define the background, `background=user`, with the command `\background` added to the preamble, like this:

```
\background{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \shade [shading=axis,top color=reddishyellow,bottom color=lightblue] (current page.north east)%
           rectangle ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.south west);%
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

This is the same code used in the xebaposter class when the background is set with `shadetb`, modified to extend the shading to the corners of the page beyond the south-west corner set by the page geometry. `[xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-1cm]` was found by trial and when the class option, `margin=3cm` was provided. The colors `reddishyellow` and `lightblue` come from the OP.

This is the MWE. I used the XB Yas font available [here](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/xb-yas).

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\RequirePackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pgf-cmykshadings}
\documentclass[margin=3cm,a0paper,landscape,persian,showframe]{xebaposter} % <- added margin
\usepackage{ptext}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{XB Yas}

\definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.68,0.25,0.0,0.0}
%\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1}

\background{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \shade [shading=axis,top color=reddishyellow,bottom color=lightblue] (current page.north east)%
           rectangle ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.south west);%
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{poster}{
    borderColor=reddishyellow,
    headerColorOne=black,
    headerColorTwo=lightblue,
    headerborder=closed,
    headershape=roundedleft,
    headerfont=\Large,
    columns=4,
    background=user,%user,%plain,none ,shadetb,
    %background=none
  }{}{}{}

  \begin{posterbox}[column=0,span=4,row=0]{جداسازی}
    \ptext[6]
  \end{posterbox}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ross, but if i add the option [column=0,span=4,row=0] the text will exceed the left margins, please see the new version of MWE.

Comment: @Abdelhak You are welcome. The new answer appears to be a satisfactory solution.